# I need Illustrator script to find a combination of numbers in a range

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator

I need to be able to find colors based on the RGB number brake down. I am not 100% how to make this work. Here is kind of what i am looking for.

```
\var aDoc = app.activeDocument;  

var rgbCol = new RGBColor();  
rgbCol.red = x >= 200  &&  x <= 220;  
rgbCol.green = y >= 200 &&  y <= 220;  
rgbCol.blue = z >= 200 &&  z <= 220;  

aDoc.defaultFillColor = rgbCol;  
app.executeMenuCommand("Find Fill Color menu item");
```

Each one of the RGB numbers can be different from each other. Any ideas?

Comment: See my answer for your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51773047/illustrator-script-to-find-all-colors-in-document/51802552#51802552)

Comment: The coding worked it told me all of the different colors of gray in the order. i have been trying to play around with it a bit to instead of alert me of the color maybe change it to      ` aDoc.defaultFillColor = 'R'+'G'+'B';`     this does not quite work.