# Illustrator Script to find unique color code count coded in a document

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, color-codes

We are working on Abode Illustrator to  create SVG files, we are trying to create javaScripts to list all the color codes coded in the SVG file.

And also trying to get the count of each color coded in each objects in the SVG.

[Required Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjZmR.jpg)

[Result using JavaScript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36C3p.jpg)

We tried using the solution provided in the below link provided by @Emeeus.
Link: [Illustrator script to find all colors in document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51773047/illustrator-script-to-find-all-colors-in-document)

We opened the SVG file in a empty web page and ran the below code in the Console:

```
var doc = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
               var colors = [];

               for (let j = 0; j < doc.length; j++) {

               var styles = window.getComputedStyle(doc[j], null)

               for (let i = 0; i < styles.length; i++) {

if (typeof styles[styles[i]] !== "undefined" && styles[styles[i]].match(/rgb\([0-9, ]*\)/g)) {

let color = styles[styles[i]].replace(/(.*)(rgb\([0-9, ]*\))(.*)/g,"$2")
  if (!colors.includes(color))
    colors.push(color);

}

 }

  }
 console.log(colors)
```

It does give you the list of color codes used in the file.
But there are more 2 requirements we need:

1. The color code is in RBG form, we require the same in HEX code.
2. The count of each color code is not extracted in the output.

Getting out using the above code:
[Result using JavaScript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjZmR.jpg)

[Required Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36C3p.jpg)

Comment: Please edit your post and format the code parts properly. It's hard to read like this.

Comment: Apologies, this is the first time i'm using StackOverFlow to help resolve our query.
Have tried editing again, let me know if the query is understandable.

Thank you.